# Fake input textfield - When focus and how to push icon away from left

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/g54p4/

HTML and CSS is in jsfiddle in case if you need to see.

```
    <div class="box-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="input-icon-email cly-pvxl" name="email">
    </div>

    <div class="box-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="input-icon-email cly-pvxl" name="email">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 .box-input{
      border-left: 7px solid transparent;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .box-input:hover, 
    .box-input:focus{
        border-left: 7px solid green;
     }

    .box-input input{
        width: 100%;
        border: 0;
        padding-left: 80px;
    }

    .box-input input:focus,
    .box-input input:hover{
          outline: 1px solid #eee;

    }

    .input-icon-email{
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: middle;
      height: 34px;
      width: 34px;
      background: url('http://mbsales.com/WebAssets/email_icon1.gif') left center no-repeat;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
```

Tried fake input div so that it would display border-left green but realized when go to next field by entering tab, it won't show border-left green. other problem is if try to add border-left green in input css, it will display when focus, and image icon will be jumpy. Also wanted to push the icon away with padding left but nothing happened.

Perhaps might be doing it wrong. 
Help appreciated.

Comment: instead of `padding-left`, try replacing your `left` in the background to `30px`... `background: url('http://mbsales.com/WebAssets/email_icon1.gif') 30px center no-repeat;`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g54p4/1/)

add this:

```
.box-input input{ border-left: 7px solid transparent;}
```

and return the hover style to the input:

```
.box-input input:focus,
.box-input input:hover{
      outline: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 7px solid green;


}
```

Comment: thanks. almost there, but when outline is hovered or focused, can see a bit line before border-left green.. is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You want the left side to only show the green border and all other sides with the 1 pixel outline?

Comment: correct i want left side to show green border while other 3 sides with 1px outline. ah i guess it can use border for three sides, but the problem is that i have border top and bottom for each textfield, so if add border right, top and bottom, it will look jumpy. hmm

Answer (score 1):

You can as well use box-shadow : **[DEMO outset](http://jsfiddle.net/g54p4/2/)** - **[DEMO inset](http://jsfiddle.net/g54p4/3/)**

```
input:focus {
    box-shadow: -7px 0 0 0 green;
}
```

or even

```
input:focus {
    box-shadow: inset 7px 0 0 0 green;
}
```

This will be added to any borders already here and remains as long as input has focus. ouset box-shadow may change outline renderer from browser to browser , inset should not and inset will drawn hover background if any.